# Convert datetime format in SAS

Tags: sas

How can I convert something like this:

> 1January2006        11:00PM

into this:

> 1JAN06:23:00:00

Currently, I have import the date from a txt and merge the date and time together:

```
data date_time;
infile 'X:\date_time.txt' dlm=',' ;
length date $20;
input news $  time $ date  $ words $;
datetime =date || time;
run;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with messy data can be tricky.  In this case, you need to break the incoming text string into parts, then convert the parts into a datetime value.  Here is an example that should help:

```
data want;
  input @1 date_string $23.;

  length DatePart $15 TimePart $7 DayMonthPart $5 YearPart $4;
  drop DatePart TimePart DayMonthPart YearPart;

  format DT datetime.;

  DatePart = scan(date_string,1);
  TimePart = scan(date_string,2);

  YearPart = substr(DatePart,length(DatePart) - 3);
  if notalpha(DatePart,2) = 2  /* Second character is a digit */
     then DayMonthPart =        substr(DatePart,1,5);
     else DayMonthPart = '0' || substr(DatePart,1,4);

  DT = input(DayMonthPart || YearPart || ' ' || TimePart,datetime.);

  put date_string= / DT= /;

  datalines;
30september2012 11:00PM
1january2012 11:00PM
31january2012 11:00PM
1july2012 11:00AM
30july2012 1:00AM
run;
```

The code above is intentionally verbose so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is probably a more elegant way, here's one option:

```
data test;
  length dt $30;
  dt="1January2006 11:00PM";
  if length(dt)=20 then dt="0"||dt;
  date_num=input(substr(scan(dt,1),1,5)||compress(substr(scan(dt,1),3),,'kd'),date9.);
  time_num=input(scan(dt,2),time.);
  dt_num=dhms(date_num,hour(time_num),minute(time_num),0);
  put dt_num datetime.;
run;
```

The log output gives:

```
01JAN06:23:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your easiest method is to read in the date and time using date and time informats instead of text.  You can then use the DHMS function to create the datetime column and apply your required format.

```
datetime=dhms(date,0,0,time);
```